# After "unlocking" our not provided keywords, we aren't seeing the actual keywords in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, wordpress, not-provided

We are trying to improve our SEO Ranking but we notice a problem or maybe a discrepancy in what the Google Analytics data is showing us.

We use this step by step for not provided:

https://blog.kissmetrics.com/unlock-keyword-not-provided/

but The result after 2 years is :

[image]

We should be getting actual keyword right?

A brief background

We use Wordpress with Yoast Premium

What are we doing wrong? or this is normal?

Comment: There is no way to get they actual keyword associated with some page view.   Google just doesn't share that information anymore.   The best you can do view the aggregated "search analytics" stats in Google Search Console and link those to your Google Analytics account.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct result of using method 1. What that filter is doing is changing the word "not provided" to the letters "np" followed by the landing page (the request URI in Field B). Unfortunately, there isn't any way to get organic keywords from Google back into Google Analytics reports.

The second method of viewing Search Queries (which is what is available in Google Search Console) is your best option to get the keywords (though this data isn't always accurate either and even at its best, you can't connect keywords to pages).

One other option to explore is a service called [Keyword Hero](https://keyword-hero.com). I've been testing it out for some of my clients and it seems to get more keywords back into analytics, though I can't speak to the accuracy of the data.

Comment: Thank you @MatthewEdgar's , a couple of daya ago I Saw this service, but what I don't understand is why KEYWORDHERO creates a New property , and if this New property Most be added like a New Analytics code inside your wbesite . Is kind of Confusing (for me of course)